# Remove shadow below actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

I use actionbarsherlock. The piece of code below is responsible for changing it's background to a custom one.

```
<style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbar_bg</item>
    <...>  
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
    <..>
</style>
```

And it works for actionbarsherlock (on versions below honeycomb). But in ICS I have a shadow below actionbar which I don't want. **What is the style item to make it disappear?**

Answer (score 496, accepted):

> What is the style item to make it disappear?

In order to remove the shadow add this to your app theme:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

**UPDATE:**
As @Quinny898 stated, on Android 5.0 this has changed, you have to call `setElevation(0)` on your action bar. Note that if you're using the support library you must call it to that like so:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: Isn't it a style to remove the shadow from below the status bar, not the actionbar?

Comment: Thanks, it disappeared. Important thing to note is that this line of code should appear in the app theme, not the actionbar style.

Comment: I works! What need be clear is that this line of code should be added in the App Theme Tag, not the ActionBar Theme tag.

Comment: And another  thing that also should be noted is that you should change your theme in values,values-v11,value-v14   (if you use toolbar ,ignore this)

Comment: for pre-lollipop , is it possible to do it only in code instead of using XML ?

Comment: for pre-lollipop devices `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);` doesn't work. So you've put `<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>` in your application theme. I had the similar problem. Now I've both of them. setElevation from and added windowContentOverlay item in application theme. setElevation works for android 5.0 and up while the other works for pre-lollipop. Cheers!

Comment: Thank you very much. It works. As mentioned by the others, the code needs to be put inside the AppTheme, not the ActionBarTheme.

Comment: Important to note, when using `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);`, you  must call this before `setContentView()` for this to work.

Answer (score 147):

For Android 5.0, if you want to set it directly into a style use:

```
<item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
```

and for Support library compatibility use:

```
<item name="elevation">0dp</item>
```

Example of style for a AppCompat light theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <!-- remove shadow below action bar -->
    <!-- <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item> -->
    <!-- Support library compatibility -->
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Then apply this custom ActionBar style to you app theme:

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Theme.MyApp.ActionBar</item>
</style>
```

For pre 5.0 Android, add this too to your app theme:

```
<!-- Remove shadow below action bar Android < 5.0 -->
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Comment: Did not work for me for pre 5.0 devices. The problem was, I added the `windowContentOverlay` to the action bar theme, not to the app theme.

Comment: I'm sorry but im trying to do the  opposite thing, Make the elevation shadow actually appear on pre-lollipop devices (I've managed to do it with `android:elevation` for Lollipop devices). I can't manage to do it, using this approach. I believe it would be fairly straight. Put a non-zero value for elevation attributes and thats would be it.

Comment: It should be visible by default if you don't touch android:windowContentOverlay attribute, maybe check that you are using a correct theme... I think you need to use an AppCompat theme.

Comment: but how to deal with `android:windowContentOverlay` on pre lollipop API? I cannot compile if my minSDK is pre lollipop but target is 21?

Comment: You should be able to compile. Maybe try to target 22 or 23 instead if possible.

Comment: @Sloosh can we do this programmatically?

Comment: This worked but only when I used `<style name="Theme.MyApp.ActionBar" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">` without `style/` in `parent` attribute.

Comment: This worked for `actionBarStyle`, but not working for `actionBarTheme`. Why is that so?

Answer (score 104):

On Android 5.0 this has changed, you have to call setElevation(0) on your action bar. Note that if you're using the support library you must call it to that like so:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

It's unaffected by the windowContentOverlay style item, so no changes to styles are required

Comment: Do you have to do this for every activity, or is there a quick method for it to apply to all activities? I will add this all my activities for now. Thanks!

Comment: As it's like any other actionbar method (eg. the title), I'd say every activity

Comment: That's a shame. It would be nice to set parameters like this in the styles.xml file. Maybe that will come in a future update

Comment: this is not working on lower versions than 5.0. Isn't the support actionbar supposed to be compatible with all previous devices?

Comment: same as @splinter123 here :( Wonder how I can remove the shadows on pre-Lollipop when using AppCompat.

Comment: Have a look at at my solution above, it explains how to do with pre-Lollipop and AppCompat.

Comment: this works but then, I have a back arrow in the actionbar, which is not receiving any input. Any ideas on how to solve this ?

Comment: it is not work for me on custom Toolbar. I create a Custom toolbar in xml and add it to SupportAction bar

Answer (score 56):

add `app:elevation="0dp"` in AppBarLayout for hiding shadow in appbar

Comment: Look everyone, just apply this solution and forget what everyone else has said. Thanks Man! it works! Very simple solution!

Comment: Use like this:
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

Comment: @MarcoFerrari Use this in case of AppBarLayout  as 'getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);' doesn't work.

Answer (score 39):

If you are working with ActionBarSherlock

In your theme add this:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
    ....
    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    ....
</style>
```

Comment: this is a better answer, it specifies the compatibility item

Answer (score 30):

You must set `app:elevation="0dp"` in the `android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout` and then it works.

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    app:elevation="0dp"... >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" >


    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

Comment: this causes, that the shadow of the AppBar is away everywhere - how can I control that programmatically?

Answer (score 19):

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

but not

```
android:elevation="0dp"
```

worked for me on android L

Answer (score 3):

I have this same problem, and I have successfully solved this problem. All you have to do is just change the elevation to 0 floating point value in that activity in which you want to remove the elevation.

If you want to change it in an activity called `MyActivity.java` so you have to get the `ActionBar` first.

First import the `ActionBar` class

```
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
```

after importing you have to initialize a variable of action bar and set its elevation to 0.

```
 private ActionBar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    .
    .
    toolbar=getSupportActionBar();
    toolbar.setElevation(0);
    .
    .
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Solution for **Kotlin** (Android 3.3, Kotlin 1.3.20)

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    supportActionBar!!.elevation = 0f
}
```

Comment: Not sure why this is downvoted (I'm new at Kotlin) but this worked for me where others didn't

Answer (score 1):

For Xamarin Developers, please use : `SupportActionBar.Elevation = 0;` for `AppCompatActivity` or `ActionBar.Elevation = 0;` for non-compat Activities

Answer (score 1):

Try This it helped me without changing theme . Put Your AppBarLayout inside any layout.Hope this will help you

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="false"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
       android:background="@color/white">
        <ImageView
            android:src="@drawable/go_grocery_logo"
            android:layout_width="108dp"
            android:layout_height="32dp" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>


</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this `toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);` to inside OnCreate method. The add this:
`android:elevation="0dp" android:background="@android:color/transparent` 
to your toolbar xml file.

Answer (score 0):

For those working on fragments and it disappeared after setting `toolbar.getBackground().setAlpha(0);` or any disappearance, i think you have to bring your AppBarLayout to the last in the xml, so its Fragment then AppBarLayout then relativelayout/constraint/linear whichever u use.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
outLineAmbientShadowColor="@null"
```