# Android transparent ActionBar with ActionSherlock on v19

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock, android-4.4-kitkat

I changed the AndroidManifest from

```
android:targetSdkVersion="18"
```

to

```
android:targetSdkVersion="19"
```

Now i have a issue with my transparent actionbar using a png

this i the actionbar layout i want to, on a N4 with v18:

[image: v18 nice actionbar]

and this is the actionbar on v19 on the n5, there is a "little" transparency, but not full:

[image: v19, bad actionbar]

This is my theme setup in values/styles.xml:

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
    <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>

    <!-- Actionbar Background -->
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/My.Actionbar</item>
</style>
<style name="My.Actionbar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="background">@drawable/actionbarbg</item>
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbarbg</item>
</style>
```

and this in the values-v19/styles.xml

```
 <style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock.Light">
      <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/My.Actionbar</item>
      <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/My.Actionbar</item>
      <item name="windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
      <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
</style>

<style name="My.Actionbar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/actionbarbg</item>
</style>
```

If i change back the targetSdk to 18, it also works on the Nexus5

Any Idea whats my mistake?

Comment: I am not sure where we are suppose to be looking, I really dont see a difference. Could you maybe point out your concern?

Comment: i made a blue border around a area. its just a small difference between the grey bar and the magenta background, the trans magenta is a little bit lighter then the background of the activity.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The issue you are seeing is that there is a drop shadow that normally sits below the action bar. You can remove it by adding

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

to the styles for your apptheme in the values-v19 folder.

Source: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar)

Comment: thanks! but is this drop shadow since v19? why it isn´t visible on v18?

Comment: @develth I don't know, but they may have added it in KitKat as part of the visual changes they made.