# Remove shadows below actionbar appcompat

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar, android-actionbar-compat

Is it possible to remove the shadow below the `Actionbar`?

I am using the AppCompat v7 library.

Comment: look at more complete answer in http://stackoverflow.com/a/27203224/1966662 hope solve your problem

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This works with AppCompat:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTheme</item>
</style>

<style name="MyActionBarTheme" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid">
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score -4):

Add this in style.xml :

```
<style name="MyTheme" parent="Theme.Sherlock">
....
<item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
....
```

Comment: Any other way to do it dynamically ?

Comment: I also use v7 with min-sdk=11 but "windowContentOverlay" gives "No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'windowContentOverlay'" error in Eclipse. Any help?

Comment: The question is regarding AppCompat, not Sherlock.