# How to replace shadow under the ActionBar with a solid line?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I have seen this answer for removing the shadow which accomplishes half of the task:
[Remove shadow below actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar)

Any idea how to place a simple solid line under the tabs?

I suspect the answer may be to color the background and add a 1dp marginBottom somewhere in the theme, but I can not figure out where.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a drawable that is a solid line and use is as the `windowContentOverlay`

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@drawable/solid_line</item>
```

In `res/drawable/solid_line.xml`:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">

    <solid android:color="@android:color/black" />

    <size android:height="1dp" />
</shape>
```