# Lollipop linear layout gradient background

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop

I've create a very simple linear layout below the action bar but now in Android 5.0 Lollipop (emulator) it's applied a gradient as you can see but it isn't set at all! I simply set the android:background of linear layout. Is it a bug? How can I avoid that gradient? In the developer preview there wasn't any problem.

[image]

Comment: Make screen with no Action bar like:  android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.NoActionBar.Fullscreen"  in android manifest

Comment: @AmolTate No I can't. I need the action bar as you can see.

Answer (score 1):

Found a workaround for Lillipop:

```
<style name="MyTheme.BigActionBarStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Material.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="android:elevation">0dp</item> <----With this line work
        <item name="android:displayOptions"></item>
</style>
```

Comment: You could also set your action bar background to null or transparent, which will prevent it from casting a shadow.

Answer (score -1):

In order to remove the shadow add this to your app theme:

```
<style name="MyAppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar)

Comment: Yes this issue already submitted to Google (Android) developer team:https://code.google.com/p/android-developer-preview/issues/detail?id=1486.. Sorry for wrong answer

Comment: Material doesn't use a window content overlay. It's an actual elevation-based shadow.