# Remove shadow between actionbar and tabs

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I am trying to remove the shadow between my tabs and the actionbar, and I want to have shadow below the slidingTabs. I have implemented my tabs with [this](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Sliding-Tabs-with-PagerSlidingTabStrip) approach. Which means it is not possible to configure the actionbar layout with the normal theme approach.

Here is a picture of what I want:
[image]

How can I do this?

Edit:
Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip
    android:id="@+id/tabs"
    app:pstsShouldExpand="true"
    app:pstsTextAllCaps="true"
    app:pstsIndicatorHeight="5dp"
    app:pstsIndicatorColor="#FFFFFF"        
    app:pstsDividerColor="#CE2A2F"        
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:background="#CE2A2F"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="48dp">
</com.astuetz.PagerSlidingTabStrip>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

Comment: try: http://stackoverflow.com/a/12246593/3736955

Comment: can you please update your question with the xml file

Comment: put the pagerstrip inside the viewpager

Comment: Why? It works well splitted, and the documentation has it this way

Comment: If you want it the way you won't do or else don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On pre-Lollipop devices you need to set `android:windowContentOverlay` to null.

On lollipop you can call `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0)` or set the elevation attribute in your Action Bar style.

Comment: I get this error when trying getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0):  The method setElevation(int) is undefined for the type ActionBar

Comment: Which version of v7 appcompat library
do you use?

Comment: No idea? How can i check it?

Comment: If you use gradle you can check in build.gradle the row compile "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0" (in this case the version in 22). Unfortunately I don't think there is an easy way to check the version on eclipse. You need the version 21+ to use setElevation.

Comment: Got it working, do you know how to add the shadow below the tabs?