# Get rid of this line separator between my action-bar and pagertabview:

Tags: android, android-actionbar, styles

I'm trying to get rid of this line separator between my action-bar and pagertabview:

[image]

How did Google achieve this?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't really a line separator, it is a shadow indicating that the Action Bar is at a higher elevation than the tab bar.

Assuming you are using AppCompat, you can use [`ViewCompat.setElevation()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewCompat.html#setElevation(android.view.View,%20float)) to set the elevation on your tabs for devices that support it (those running API 21+).

Your code might look something like this:

```
View tabs = findViewById(R.id.the_tabs_id)
ViewCompat.setElevation(tabs, getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.action_bar_elevation));
```

I am using 4dp as the `action_bar_elevation` dimension.

**Pre 5.0:**

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: Thanks, I need this to work on API 16+. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: Your screenshot appears to be from a device running Lollipop- are you seeing the shadow on devices running API 16? Are you using a Toolbar or the default Action Bar?

Comment: My Note 3 is running Kitkat, Default actionbar.

Comment: I edited you answer, I found the solution. I'll mark it as correct

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar/27203224#27203224