# Android action bar showing faded on my phone

Tags: android, android-studio

I am currently learning Android Studio and I'm having a problem when I run the app on my Samsung Note 3.

Problem:-
1. The Action Bar looks faded on my phone.
2. Menu Button is not showing on my phone.

Screenshot on my Samsung Note 3
https://imageshack.com/i/exgIBDFBp

Screenshot on Android studio
https://imageshack.com/i/p8qSUa9Sp

Answer (score 0):

Are you defining a `Toolbar` in your XML? If so try removing the `eleveation` attribute.

Comment: Hi, I have not defined a Toolbar in my XML. Even if I create a brand new project and run it on my phone, I will have the same problem

Comment: I have the same phone as you, how do you not have this button? Is it like this for all apps?

Comment: what button? menu button? Yes all the projects in my Android Studio, the menu button is not showing for some reason when I run in my phone :(

Answer (score 0):

[My question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29608675/get-rid-of-this-line-separator-between-my-action-bar-and-pagertabview/29608922#29608922) had a similar issue. However, the Note 3 has a "physical" button for this at the bottom. This could override your apps.

I think your `onCreateOptionsMenu` - `MenuInflater` is the issue, change to the following and see if that works for you:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity, menu);
    return true;
}
```

**For elevation issues:**

For Android 5.0, if you want to set it directly into a style use:

```
<item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
```

and for Support library compatibility use:
    0dp

For pre 5.0 Android, add this too to your app theme:

```
<!-- Remove shadow below action bar Android < 5.0 -->
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Comment: Hi Im using Holo Light DarkActionBar theme. When I add <item name="elevation">0dp</item>, I get compile error: Error:(6, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'elevation'.

Comment: Try the  <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item> , under apptheme

Comment: Hi, tried that no errors but still did not solve the problem :(

Comment: You do know that the Note 3 has a physical button and the emulator doesn't right? So if you press that button what happens?