# Overlaying content above AppBarLayout using new Material Design

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I want to achieve something like that. (not the FAB or the Snackbar). How can i create a layout, overlaying the AppBarLayout? Like this! (For Example)

[image: AppBarLayout with overlaying content]

Like Play Store:

[image: Just like on the Play Store]

My AppBarLayout with CoordinatorLayout and NestedScrollView with RelativeLayout as content looks like this:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/rootLayout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/_118sdp"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:contentScrim="@color/mpc_pink"
        app:expandedTitleMarginStart="@dimen/_40sdp"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <de.mypostcardstore.widgets.ItemImageView
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:src="@color/mpc_pink"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
            app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/article_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:contentScrim="@color/mpc_pink"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />


    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="?android:colorBackground"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent".....>
```

It would be awesome if someone could help me out. I can not find anything on the internet...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the real question? Do you want a Card over an extended toolbar?

Comment: Also what do you want to happen when you scroll? From your code, it looks like you want your `AppBarLayout` to scroll entirely off the screen when you scroll - is that correct?

Comment: Pretty much like the Tablet Design of the App-Page on Google Play.http://imgur.com/7C30E7P

Comment: Not used the support library and the particular widgets you are using but have you tried setting positive padding to the scrollview and then use clipToPadding?

Answer (score 48):

Just add something like

```
app:behavior_overlapTop="64dp"
```

to your **NestedScrollView** and it will be placed above the expanded toolbar.

In addition, you should add something like

```
app:expandedTitleMarginBottom="70dp"
```

to your **CollapsingToolbarLayout** so the title does not appear under your overlaid scroll content.

Comment: This works for me too, But in my case i have viewpager instade of nested scrollview and i dont want that collapsing toolbar to scroll and collapse. but cant find solution. Tried overriding some method to disable drag, but it will move view pager below collapsing toolbar.

Comment: @PVartak any luck finding the solution for your issue?

Comment: @free_style nope. At last, I kept less area on which the user can click. Actual scroll issue never solved.

Answer (score 15):

It's quite simple, really. You could achieve that by using a combination of `ToolBar`, `FrameLayout`, and your content view (could be a `ListView` like your first example, or anything).

The idea is to make your `FrameLayout` possess the same color as your `ToolBar`, giving the illusion of `ToolBar` being much larger than it is. Then all that is left to do is to make your content view be the last (or in API 21 and above: possess the highest `elevation` attribute) so that it would appear as if it floats above the aforementioned `FrameLayout`.

See my illustration below:

[image]

Now that you got the big idea, below is some real live XML snippet for doing such thing. (I actually use this layout in one of my apps) :

```
<!-- Somewhere in your layout.xml -->

....

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/tb_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/abc_action_bar_default_height_material"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
        app:contentInsetStart="72dp"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"/>

    <!-- This is the 'faux' ToolBar I've been telling you about. This is the part that will be overlaid by the content view below. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/v_toolbar_extension"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="64dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tb_toolbar"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="2dp"/>

    <!-- Normally, I use this FrameLayout as a base for inflating my fragments. You could just use put your content view here. -->
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/ly_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tb_toolbar"
        android:elevation="3dp"/>

....
```

Note that my `ly_content` has higher elevation value than that of `v_toolbar_extension`. This is what will give you that desired 'overlaid toolbar' effect.

Last but not least, you would want to add this line somewhere in your activity's `onCreate()` :

```
/* Assuming mToolbar exists as a reference to your ToolBar in XML. */
setSupportActionBar(mTbToolbar);
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

What that codes woud do is to set your `ToolBar` elevation to zero; removing preset shadows that were given as a default to ToolBars. If you don't do this, said shadow will create a "seam" between your `ToolBar` and your `FrameLayout`, thus breaking the illusion of those two being the same.

***p.s.***, It is also important to give your content view a padding on each side. Doing so, your content view will not cover the entire width of the screen (which would render this effect useless).

---

**Note:** I see some good answers here that mentioned the absence of `FrameLayout` and instead making the `ToolBar` taller. While in theory it might work as well as my proposed solution, you might have problems when trying to manipulate scrolling; by doing that, you won't be able to separate `ToolBar` and its extension. You'll be forced to either make the `Toolbar` static or scroll all of the `ToolBar` altogether (makes scrolling a bit weird).

Add to that, the fact that you can't easily assign a custom drawable into a `Toolbar`. Hence makes it hard to follow the Google Play example you've given above. While if you're using my solution, all you'd need to do is just make your `Toolbar` transparent and assign the drawable to the `FrameLayout` instead.

Comment: How would you get this to work for pre-Lollipop devices? setElevation() won't work.

Comment: On pre-L, those shadows weren't set by `setElevation()` but by modifying your `style.xml`. Refer to here for how: http://stackoverflow.com/q/12246388/1727589

Comment: that won't look good as the toolbar will have a shadow beneath and when the toolbar collapses you will see the division between the toolbar and the framelayout that has a background color

Comment: No need to do that hack. Using `app:behavior_overlapTop` attribute can achieve that very easily, even on Older APIs (as per support lib).

Comment: saved my a** today. `app:behavior_overlapTop` does not work when we disable the scroll flag

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar requirement and I achieved it as below.

Your activity theme should extend Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.
I created a Layout XML File as:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_size_x2"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/action_bar_size"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="10dp"
                android:text="@string/app_name"
                android:textSize="24sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</LinearLayout>
```

And the Activity should be something like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Toolbar maintoolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar_main);
        setSupportActionBar(maintoolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }
}
```

I got a view like this :
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I did try to implement effects like you referred which is called `Card Toolbar in Android`, and it did work as expected. Here is my layout, Take a look at it:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@color/background_material_light" >
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_double_height"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" />
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/cardview_toolbar_spacer"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/cardview_toolbar_spacer"
    android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/white">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize" />
        <View
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="1dp"
            android:alpha="0.12"
            android:background="@android:color/black" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</FrameLayout>
```

Hope you'll be inspired.