# Shade and overlap AppBarLayout with FrameLayout

Tags: android, android-layout, popupwindow, android-appbarlayout

I'm making an app for my graduation exam.
I have a frame layout that has a black background with a 60% alpha (to shade everything that is below it). I would like that the frame layout overlaps the app bar layout and the floating button.
The only other similar question I found is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31031918/overlaying-content-above-appbarlayout-using-new-material-design), but It didn't work on my project because, as long as I understood, he only wanted to overlap a FrameLayout.

Here is the AppBarLayout with the floating button:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"/>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:elevation="4dp">

            [...]

        </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white" />
```

*Inside the relative layout up above there is a little text I need.*

Here is instead the FrameLayout:

```
<FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/blackBackground"
        android:id="@+id/addJobFrame"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:behavior_overlapTop="100dp">

        [...]

</FrameLayout>
```

*Please, note that everything is inside a CoordinatorLayout.*

The effect I want to obtain is the one on the right in [this picture](http://sniperita77.altervista.org/application_shaded.png), in fact in the frame layout I've included an external xml layout.

As an alternative, do you know any other method?

Comment: Can you please provide an image of your expected output? It will help you get quick answer from others.

Comment: @FerdousAhamed pic added

Comment: This is a custom dialog. Please see my answer. I have added full working code. Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your attached image, seems its a custom `AlartDialog`.

To create a custom dialog:

1. Design an custom layout XML `dialog_layout.xml` for your custom dialog.
2. Set this custom layout to `AlertDialog` by using `AlertDialog.Builder.setView()` method.

Here is a complete example:

**dialog_layout.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_dateStart"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:hint="Start Date"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText_dateEnd"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
        android:textColorHint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText_dateStart"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:hint="End Date"
        android:inputType="date" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button_ok"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:text="ACCETTO"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:background="#34ff00"
        android:layout_below="@id/editText_dateEnd"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**YourActivity.java**

```
    AlertDialog.Builder dialogBuilder;
    AlertDialog dialog;

    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogLayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_layout, null);

    // Views
    Button button = (Button) dialogLayout.findViewById(R.id.button_ok);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

                // Do something
            }
        });

    dialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    dialogBuilder.setView(dialogLayout);

    dialog = dialogBuilder.create();
    dialog.show();
```