# Android action bar overflow menu remove shadow

Tags: android, android-actionbar, overflow, android-appcompat, shadow

I'd like to remove shadow around my action bar overflow menu, but i haven't found any attributes allowing that. I'm extending Theme.AppCompat.

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/OverflowButton</item>
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/OverflowMenu</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarLogo</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/PopupMenuListView</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/PopupMenuListView</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu</item>
</style>
<style name="MyActionBarLogo" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>

    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
<style name="OverflowButton" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@mipmap/menu_logo</item>
</style>
<style name="OverflowMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="overlapAnchor">false</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownVerticalOffset">52dp</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownHorizontalOffset">10dp</item>
</style>
<style name="PopupMenuListView" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:divider">@drawable/menu_divider</item>
    <item name="android:dividerHeight">1dp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/white</item>
</style>
<style name="PopupMenu" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/94fqF.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You can try solution [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar)

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

**UPDATE**

```
<style name="MyActionBarLogo" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@color/white</item>
    <item name="displayOptions">useLogo|showHome</item>

    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownMenuStyle</item> 
</style>



<style name="DropDownMenuStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

Comment: That is only for actionbar shadow, which i already removed :)

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol '@style/Widget.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar',
I've added AppCompat in there so it's @style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar now, but shadow is still there.

Comment: Opps sorry, just remove the "@style/"

updated the answer again

Comment: Still no difference at all, shadow is there :/.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply the zero elevation style to the correct element, in this case actionOverflowMenuStyle.

(This is using appcompat)

```
<style name="Theme.myapp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="actionOverflowMenuStyle">@style/Theme.myapp.Widget.PopupMenu.Overflow</item>
</style>
```

Then

```
<style name="Theme.myapp.Widget.PopupMenu.Overflow" parent="Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu.Overflow">
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:popupElevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: did not work for me :(