# How to remove ActionBar shadow?

Tags: android

I'm trying to remove `ActionBar` shadow that appears in this image:

[image]

Since now I've tried to add these lines in my `xml` theme:

```
 <style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And do it programmatically like this:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

as posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12246593/760893).

But nothing is working for me...

My device is using last version of Android. Any idea on why is not working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add this property to your `Toolbar` or `AppBarLayout` (I don't know if you are using `AppBarLayout`):

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

Comment: That was it! I had to add it into the `AppBarLayout`. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
....
</style>

<style name="NoActionBarShadowTheme" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

And in **manifest**

```
<activity
    android:theme="@style/NoActionBarShadowTheme"
```

And if you are using material design,try setting your toolbar `elevation` to `0dp`.