# How to implement Toolbar Layout

Tags: android, toolbar

How do I remove the boundary between action and toolbar?

Bad Case

[image]

Good Case, I want to like it.

[image]

Activity XML

[image]

Fragment XML

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a way to remove the shadow under toolbar.

For **android 4.4 or below**, you will have to set the window content overlay in your activity theme like this

```
<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    ...
    <!--To hide shadow effect in toolbar for Android 4.4 or below-->
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

For **Android 5.0+**, you will also need to set the toolbar elevation to 0 in the activity layout like this.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...
    >

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        ...
        app:elevation="0dp">

        ...

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Actually, many people ask about this. See [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12246593/1939549)

Try to search for existing answer next time ;)

Comment: This issue is not resolved in your way. I've tried the following: Add code (getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);) in activity oncreate,  And, Add style and elevation in Fragment Xml .

Comment: how about the style? did you try to set window content overlay as null in your activity style? The fix for 4.4 below may help also on Android 5.0+ too.