# How can I remove android actionbar Shadow

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm using Android Studio for programming. Target SDK is 23 and Minimum SDK is 15

I'm trying to remove the shadow between my actionbar and my sliding tab layout. But I'm not able to.

Note : The shadow is only visible in Android 5 and upper.

I have used `<item name="elevation">0dp</item>` and `getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);`
But still it doesn't work...

[image]

**My Style.xml**

```
<resources>

<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>



<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
</style>



<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
</style>
```

**My Style V21**

```
<resources>>
<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowDrawsSystemBarBackgrounds">true</item>
    <item name="android:statusBarColor">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```

**My MainActivity.java onCreateCode:**

```
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

....

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove shadow below actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You're missing the prefix in your style.

```
<item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
```

That said you could also set it directly on your `AppBarLayout`

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```

Or what I like to do is move the `SlidingTabLayout` into the `AppBarLayout` so the shadow appears below it:

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary" app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay"
        />

    <com.ccswe.SmokingLog.views.widgets.SlidingTabLayout
        android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/tab_layout_height"
        />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image: Output from last code snippet]

Comment: Thank you men Thank you a loooooooooooooot

i moved The tab to appbar too and its fixed

Thank you and good luck

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to accept or upvote my answer if it solved your problem.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding setting the elevation to 0 with the help of the support library

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:elevation="0dp"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
```