# How do I remove the Innershadow that's on my action bar?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

[Picture Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwCs7.png)

I've tried to add this prefix and also added it to the AppBarLayout, but it doesn't work.

```html
<item name="android:elevation">0dp</item>
```

Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try something like in your style

```
<item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
```

Check this [Remove shadow below actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12246593/2826147)

On Android 5.0 this has changed, you have to call `setElevation(0)` on your action bar. Note that if you're using the support library you must call it to that like so:

```
getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: It didn't work sadly. [link](http://i.imgur.com/Zl1reUs.png) edit: i'm really new to android development :/

Comment: but where do I write getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);? And I think <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item> is supposed to go to styles rather then menu

Comment: Yes it should go in style and when you set actionbar onCreate() method of your class write there. getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);

Comment: how do I set actionbar onCreate method?

Comment: From the question, how you have set action bar and implemented actionbar shadow ?

Comment: the shadow was there when I opened a fresh project

Comment: find onCreate() in studio and paste that line