# Remove additional bar under Actionbar

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]

I would like to know how to remove the extra bar below my Actionbar? (There is addtional bar below that is similar color as the one above the Actionbar) The following code shows my styles.xml:

```
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
    <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.AppBarOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />


<!-- for tab text -->
<style name="AppTabTextAppearance" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Tab">
    <item name="android:textSize">14sp</item>
    <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
</style>
```

activity_navigation.xml

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_navigation"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_navigation"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_navigation_drawer" />
```

app_bar_navigation.xml

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

content_navigation.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context=".main.NavigationActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/app_bar_navigation">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You means the shadow below actionBar? Just see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar

Comment: Nope not the shadow, there is extra bar below the ActionBar and above the TabLayout as shown in the new image uploaded

Comment: Post your `XML` layout code here.

Comment: i think there some margins in xml please post your xml.

Comment: Thanks, uploaded xml files for your reference

Comment: Try giving this to your `Style` `<item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">false</item>`.

Comment: Thank you, but it's still there :(

Comment: Add this `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` to your `Toolbar`.

Comment: Under all my xml files? :)