# How to remove the shadow on top of DrawerLayout in android 5.0+

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, drawerlayout

I'm using API 19, and I have the following shadow showing up over my DrawerLayout in newer versions of android (API 22 for example).

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JeW38.jpg)

I want it gone, and I can't figure out how to achieve this.

What I've tried so far:
Setting elevation on **literally every element** to 0dp in the XML,
setting the elevation programatically for the DrawerLayout and Toolbar using getSupportToolbar(),
setting the shadow to an empty Drawable,
adding various other settings in style XML with no result.

Comment: did you tried all those things http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar

Comment: I did, that's the "various other settings in style XML" part, sorry I wasn't specific, there were just too many to remember.
It made no difference I'm afraid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my case just removed the line from the parent layout and the problem have solved!

```
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
```

By the way, I have also tried all the solution I have known! But there is no solution until I removed "android:fitsSystemWindows" attribute from the parent layout. Hope this will help who will suffer the same problem. Thanks.