# Android app masthead display

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, android-styles

I have created an app using Android Studio 2.3.3, choosing Empty Activity Template. After its creation I went and changed the background color to something like colorAccent and I also changed the colorPrimary to colorAccent in colors.xml.

Now, when I ran the app, following emulator display appeared.

[image]

As you can see, it displays my app name, followed by a dark line.
I don't understand where this dark line has come from and how can I get rid of this?

However, this dark line does not appear in Android Studio design mode (see screenshot below).

[image]

Comment: its shadow of actionbar my friend

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12246593/6950238) answer of [Tomer Mor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/849939/tomer-mor) Especially to "UPDATE:" part of it.

Comment: yes its action bar bottom line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is shadow of **action bar** my friend
to remove this shadow  add below lines to your theme under **res/values/style**

```
<style name="MYTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorWhite</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

now add this in manifest file this to your activity

```
<activity
android:name=".YourActivity"
android:theme="@style/MYTheme"/>
```

or try this

```
    getSupportActionBar().setElevation(0);
```

Comment: I added <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item> to my style.xml as you suggested but it is still showing the shadow.

Comment: add your apptheme  my friend

Comment: Nilesh, here is my style.xml.

Comment: @Abb i can't see you style xml file

Comment: <resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    </style>

</resources>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148890/discussion-between-abb-and-nilesh-rathod).