# Android Device actionbar shadow

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a simple android app with couple of issues -

When I run my app in emulator I can see things correctly, as shown in below screenshot. The actionbar shadow is not shown and also the font is Cursive.

[image]

But when I run my app on my mobile device (I am using MotoG, Android version 4.4.4) my app looks like as shown below -

[image]

I took this screenshot from my mobile itself and it is showing the shadow and font is no longer Cursive.

I have already had asked a previous question regarding this issue but it solved my problem partially  -
[Android app masthead display](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033408/android-app-masthead-display)

I have looked at other questions on stackoverlfow but they don't seem to be having a problem like mine so I am asking this question. Can someone help me solve this issue.

Comment: I suggest you include some relevant code, like, for example, your Theme/Styles, the relevant Manifest entry, your API levels, etc. There’s more than meet the eye.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your don't want action bar than use following code it will help you

**1 way through manifiest file**

```
<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen">
```

**2 way through theme**

```
    <style name="NoActionBar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    </style> 

    // than set this theme to your activty like this 
    <activity android:theme="@style/NoActionBar"/>
```

**3 way using java code**

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Comment: Nilesh, the 3rd way, using java code has worked. That is awesome. Thanks. But the font is still not showing Cursive. How can I fix this?

Comment: for that purpose you have to use custom font for that textview

Comment: Can you tell me how to use custom font which is Cursive? Right now my TextView code is as follows -  <TextView
                android:id="@+id/logo2TextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:fontFamily="cursive"
android:text="My First App"
android:textAlignment="center"  android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

Comment: Sorry I don't know how to add proper code with indents in this comment box.

Comment: follow this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588559/in-which-android-version-the-cursive-font-is-available

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12128331/how-to-change-fontfamily-of-textview-in-android

Comment: Nilesh, I used the links above and solved my fonts issue too. Thank you. BTW I emailed you regarding this same issue on ur gmail id. If possible kindly add me in ur google hangouts so that I can directly contact u on google chat/hangouts.