# How to remove the divider between the ActionBar and the rest of screen?

Tags: android, xml, divider

i want to remove the divider that is shown in sc.
[look at the green arrows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ks0RA.jpg)

(i have 5 fragment that are loaded in the viewpager and my frame,when i touch the tabs ,fragments change)

and this is my xml code for this activity.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="ir.myinsta.myinstaapp.MainActivity">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/header_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/actionbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@drawable/my_gradiant">


        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            style="@style/MyDrawerArrowToggle"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/helpImageView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/main_toolbar"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/gemLayout"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"

            android:clickable="true"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:paddingLeft="20dp"
            android:paddingRight="20dp">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="36dp"
                android:layout_height="36dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                android:src="@drawable/diamond_white" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/gemCountTextView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="-"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/white" />


        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>


<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:elevation="5dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="#00000000"
    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp" />


<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/myViewPager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/tab_layout"
    android:layout_below="@id/header_layout">

</android.support.v4.view.ViewPager>


<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_content"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@id/header_layout"></FrameLayout>


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/centerView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:padding="150dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

I don't know this is a divider or elevation.please help me.
using styles? or what?

Comment: Maybe remove the `elevation` ?

Comment: what do you mean? in which line?

Comment: Take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar)

Comment: Add `app:elevation="0dp"` inside `Toolbar`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Remove shadow below actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar)

Answer (score 0):

Try to add `app:elevation="0dp"` in your ToolBar.

Like this :-

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main_toolbar"
            style="@style/MyDrawerArrowToggle"
            app:elevation="0dp"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/toolbar_height"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true">
    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Or you can use:-

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:elevation="0dp">              
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```