How to remove borders from action bar
Solved!
I did this:
themes.xml
<item name="elevation">0dp</item>


I am working on a music app in kotlin, I have a problem, after I set a transparent background in themes for my custom action bar, the action bar has some borders. How to remove them? I will be grateful for any help
Image:
Looks like
Code:
action_bar.xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/actionBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?actionBarSize"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

                <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent">

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/buttonBack"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_back" />

                    <TextView
                        android:id="@+id/appTitle"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="32dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/app_name"
                        android:textColor="@color/white"
                        android:textSize="27sp"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/buttonBack"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

                    <ImageButton
                        android:id="@+id/songListButton"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="0dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_music" />
                </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


themes

<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Base.Theme.MusicApplication" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/black</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MusicApplication" parent="Base.Theme.MusicApplication" />
</resources>


I don't even have any idea why this could be... I checked the code, I haven't set the borders for the action bar before

Thats looks like something wrong with your theme

I wish I knew what..

Add this to the themes:
<item name="elevation">0dp</item>

themes
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="Base.Theme.MusicApplication" parent="Theme.AppCompat.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="elevation">0dp</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/white</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Theme.MusicApplication" parent="Base.Theme.MusicApplication" />
</resources>


try
setElevation(0)

or add attribute:
 app:elevation="0dp"

in your AppBarLayout tag

Unfortunately, it didn't help.

Oh sorry. Hope this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246388/remove-shadow-below-actionbar

wow, I was looking at the answers to that question, but for some reason I missed one of the answers.
This helped me:
themes
<item name="elevation">0dp</item>.
Thank you!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
